# Unable to start emulator from command line

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager, avd-manager

I am trying to run the below shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sdkmanager "emulator" "system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"
echo no | avdmanager create avd -n "Android" -k "system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64" --device 'Nexus 6P'
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd Android -no-audio -no-boot-anim -no-snapshot -timezone Asia/Phnom_penh
```

I have added the ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_AVD_HOME to my PATH (Note: I am using macos with zsh) and i have sourced the zshrc file and also restarted the terminal but keep getting the below error:

> ./start_emulator.sh: line 3: sdkmanager: command not found
>
> ./start_emulator.sh: line 4: avdmanager: command not found
>
> PANIC: Unknown AVD name [ANDROID], use -list-avds to see valid list. ANDROID_AVD_HOME
> is defined but there is no file Android.ini in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME/.android/avd (Note:
> Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,
> $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd, and $HOME/.android/avd)

Comment: Where have you defined the PATH variable in? Did you define in a shell-specific configuration file? It's probably also because you've defined your script to run in `bash` instead of the default `zsh` shell as seen in the first line of your script and you've probably configured the PATH variable on only your zsh config.

Comment: But i am using zsh as my default shell(so i have added it only to my zshrc file), do i still need to add it to bashrc file?

Comment: The solution here is to change the shell you're using to run the script in. See this guide on what a shebang is for more info: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang (in this case, just change `bash` to `zsh` and you're good to go!)

Comment: The error still remains, after changing it to #!/bin/zsh.
Additionally i also get the error: Broken AVD system path.

Comment: But as I've mentioned in my original comment, _where have you defined the PATH variable_ and how have you defined it, as well as the other environmental variables?

Comment: I have added the below variables to my .zshrc file
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$PATH

Comment: What about the `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` variable, as per what the error is mentioning? Did you define that?

Comment: Yes added as below:
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME/.android/avd
export PATH=ANDROID_AVD_HOME:$PATH

Comment: From the comment you pasted, it seems that you're missing a dollar sign from the `export PATH=ANDROID_AVD_HOME:$PATH` line. A dollar sign should be added before the `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` part.

Comment: If you notice the error it says ANDROID_AVD_HOME is defined but there is no Android.ini

Comment: I think i pasted it wrong but i has the $ sign prefixed

Comment: Did you ensure that you've exported the environmental variables in the correct sequencing?

Comment: yes the order is correct

Answer (score 0):

Changing the shell script to below does the job:

```
 #!/bin/zsh

cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
./sdkmanager "emulator" "system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"

echo no | ./avdmanager create avd -n "Android" -k "system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64" --device 'Nexus 6P' 

$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd Android -no-audio-no-boot-anim -no-snapshot -timezone Asia/Phnom_penh
```

Also running the commands individually(after moving to the folder) seem to work.Not sure if its a permission issue.